# DPLYR fails to compile on Mac

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

I've done all the normal steps. Restarting things, updating things, etc...

I have the latest version of MacOS with the latest version of Xcode and the Apple Developer Tools.

I installed R via homebrew and have tried updating everything there. I have not tried updating RStudio but i installed it in January, should be ok. Especially because i tried it using the commandline and it did not work.

Now i've ran out of things to update i don't know what to do next? Try reinstalling R and Rstudio? What do you think my issue is here?

Error message:

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dplyr_0.8.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1378766 bytes (1.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DRCPP_DEFAULT_INCLUDE_CALL=false -DCOMPILING_DPLYR -DRCPP_USING_UTF8_ERROR_STRING -DRCPP_USE_UNWIND_PROTECT -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include" -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/plogr/include" -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/dplyr.h:4:
In file included from ../inst/include/dplyr/main.h:6:
In file included from ../inst/include/dplyr/workarounds/static_assert.h:17:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:655:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/gethostuuid.h:39:17: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
int gethostuuid(uuid_t, const struct timespec *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_NA);
                ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/dplyr.h:4:
In file included from ../inst/include/dplyr/main.h:6:
In file included from ../inst/include/dplyr/workarounds/static_assert.h:17:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:662:27: error: unknown type name 'uuid_t'; did you mean 'uid_t'?
int      getsgroups_np(int *, uuid_t);
                              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_uid_t.h:31:31: note: 'uid_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_uid_t        uid_t;
                              ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/dplyr.h:4:
In file included from ../inst/include/dplyr/main.h:6:
In file included from ../inst/include/dplyr/workarounds/static_assert.h:17:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:664:27: error: unknown type name 'uuid_t'; did you mean 'uid_t'?
int      getwgroups_np(int *, uuid_t);
                              ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_uid_t.h:31:31: note: 'uid_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_uid_t        uid_t;
                              ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/dplyr.h:4:
In file included from ../inst/include/dplyr/main.h:6:
In file included from ../inst/include/dplyr/workarounds/static_assert.h:17:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:727:31: error: unknown type name 'uuid_t'; did you mean 'uid_t'?
int      setsgroups_np(int, const uuid_t);
                                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_uid_t.h:31:31: note: 'uid_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_uid_t        uid_t;
                              ^
In file included from RcppExports.cpp:4:
In file included from ./../inst/include/dplyr.h:4:
In file included from ../inst/include/dplyr/main.h:6:
In file included from ../inst/include/dplyr/workarounds/static_assert.h:17:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config/platform/macos.hpp:28:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/config/detail/posix_features.hpp:18:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/unistd.h:729:31: error: unknown type name 'uuid_t'; did you mean 'uid_t'?
int      setwgroups_np(int, const uuid_t);
                                  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_uid_t.h:31:31: note: 'uid_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_uid_t        uid_t;
                              ^
5 errors generated.
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/library/dplyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/rt/02lg8g252b7fc8c9klpqdrvh0000gn/T/RtmpMSBgAs/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

Comment: The SDK changed, which requires a change in Rcpp that was not seen prior to the last Rcpp release as nobody, CRAN included, tested with that SDK.  You need to update Rcpp which is a one-liner:  Do `install.packages("Rcpp", repos="http://rcppcore.github.io/drat")` to get an updated Rcpp (and see the Rcpp repo issues for more details).  After that proceed as usual.

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much!